# How to check $\mathrm{Spec}(R[T_0,\dots, T_n,1/T_i])\to \mathrm{Spec}(R[T_0/T_i,\dots, T_n/T_i])$ is epimorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is related to Iitaka, *Algebraic Geometry*, Chpt 1, sec 18 b).

Let $W_i=D(T_i)$ of $\mathrm{Spec}(R[T_0,\dots, T_n])$ for all $i$. Then there is inclusion map $R[T_0/T_i,\dots ,T_n/T_i]\to R[T_0,\dots, T_n,1/T_i]$. Note that the former ring is open set of $T_i\neq 0$ of $P^n_R$. So this induces $W_i\to P^n_R$ with image lying in $T_i\neq 0$ of $P^n_R$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ If $R$ is a algebraically closed field, then I would expect $\mathrm{Spec}(R[T_0,\dots, T_n,1/T_i])\to \mathrm{Spec}(R[T_0/T_i,\dots, T_n/T_i])$ is epimorphism as topological space where I will forget about sheaves. Is there an easy way to see this is topological homeomorphism? It is not clear whether I can even apply integrality argument here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity let $i = 0$.
Notice that $R[T_0/T_0,\dots ,T_n/T_0]= R[T_1/T_0,\dots ,T_n/T_0]:=S$ and
$R[T_0,\dots, T_n,1/T_0] = S[T_0,\frac1{T_0}]$. Under $S \to S[T_0,\frac1{T_0}]$, the preimages of the primes of the form $T_0 - a$, where $a \in R \setminus \{0\}$ are all $(0)$. Or one can compare the Krull dimension of these two rings.

Thus, the map on the spectra is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: I did realize yesterday that was not homeomorphism from krull dimension counting but why should it be surjection? In other words, there is $A^{n+1}_R-\{0\}\to P_R^n$ epimorphism. I would hope on above charts, it is epimorphism.

Comment: Oh, I did not think that was part of your question. Consider the composition of morphisms $S \to S[T_0] \to S[T_0,\frac1{T_0}]$. Between $S$ and $S[T_0]$, any prime ideal of $S$ extends to a prime ideal in $S[T_0]$, and this extension contracts to itself. Between the latter two rings you are only missing the prime ideal generated by $T_0$, but this cannot be extended from $S$.

Comment: I think I see the picture clear now. So roughly speaking $S\to S[T_0, 1/T_0]$ sees all the primes of $S$ which follows from freeness of $S[T_0,1/T_0]$ over $S$.(i.e. $S/p\to S/p[T_0,1/T_0]$ is still embedding.) I guess higher dimensional case follows from this argument as well. Thanks.